# How to load repeater controls after the page load in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load two repeater controls after the asp.net page is loaded completely. These two controls are populated by a button click event. Instead of the button being clicked by the user, I want that to be clicked by an ajax call - or by any other means - after the page is loaded.

I have followed the technique described here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1452988.aspx?how+to+load+gridview+after+the+page+is+completely+loaded.

Essentially it uses `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);` Once the pageLoaded event handle is obtained, it uses javascript to call the button click event. While it sort of works, the issue is that the page loading and the button click events are executed repeatedly. Because of this, the page flickers constantly. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Note: The site has a master page which has the scriptmanager.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
...More code here...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
    function pageLoaded(sender, args) {

        var hdnLoadedPage = $get('<%= hdnLoaded.ClientID %>');
        var btnApplyFilter = $get('<%= btnFilter.ClientID %>');
        if (hdnLoadedPage != 'Yes') {

            btnApplyFilter.click();
        }
    }
     </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you do in the Page_Load Event? Do you check whether it is a (ajax) postback or not?

Comment: I don't check in the page load event. I am calling the btnFilter click event from js. I have updated my question showing the js code. Thanks

Comment: By flickers constantly, do you means it keeps executing the btnApplyFilter (infinite loop) or just flickers once?

Comment: It keeps executing the btnApplyFilter in an infinite loop. Thanks

Comment: how/where do you initialize hdnLoadedPage? It is responsible to turn off the constant reload.